# Unable to deploy static website using CircleCI

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows, circleci-orb

**Summary**: I'm trying to automate the deployment of a static site (gatsby) to an S3 bucket using a CircleCI orb, but I keep getting the following error:

**#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
aws configure set aws_access_key_id 

$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 

--profile default
The config profile (*******) could not be found
Exited with code exit status 255
CircleCI received exit code 255**

I already checked my environment variable for AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID in an AWS context I setup in CircleCI. I searched for some answers on the circleci official forum, I tried the adviced offered here https://discuss.circleci.com/t/you-must-specify-a-region-you-can-also-configure-your-region-by-running-aws-configure-exited-with-code-255/14392, but still no progress fixing the issue. I'd appreciate if anyone could give me a hand.

Also, here's my CircleCI *config.yml* file

```
version: 2.1

executors:
  node_executor:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12.19.1

orbs:
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@1.3.1
  aws-s3: circleci/aws-s3@2.0.0

jobs:

  setup_gatsby:

    executor: node_executor
    working_directory: ~/application
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Update npm
          command: "sudo npm install -g npm@latest"
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          name: Restoring package.json cache
      - run:
          name: Install npm
          command: npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          name: Saving package.json cache
          paths:
            - node_modules
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-repo-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
          paths:
            - ~/application
  build_gatsby:
    executor: node_executor
    working_directory: ~/application
    steps:
      - restore_cache:
          key: v1-repo-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
      - restore_cache:
          key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run:
          name: Build
          command: |
            npm run clean
            npm run build
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-repo-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
          paths:
            - ~/application
  deploy_gatsby:
    executor: aws-cli/default
    working_directory: ~/application/public
    steps:
      - restore_cache:
          key: v1-repo-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
      - aws-s3/sync:
          from: .
          to: AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME 
          arguments: |
            --acl public-read \
            --cache-control "max-age=86400"
          aws-access-key-id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          aws-secret-access-key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          aws-region: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

workflows:
  version: 2.1
  build:
    jobs:
      - setup_gatsby
      - build_gatsby:
          context: aws
          requires:
            - setup_gatsby
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
      - deploy_gatsby:
          context: aws
          requires:
            - build_gatsby
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx8Zy.png)

Comment: Are you still having this issue when using the latest versions of each orb ([circleci/aws-cli@3.1.3](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-cli?version=3.1.3) and [circleci/aws-s3@3.0.0](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-s3?version=3.0.0))?